# SQLite and .NET UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, sqlite

I've decided to use SQLite for a small project. However, I've run into a problem. SQLite comes with 2 different .dll files. One of them I have added as a reference. The other one can't be added as a reference because it's "not a valid assembly or COM component". That doesn't matter though because it just needs to be in a folder where the first .dll (the one already added as a reference) can find it. So naturally I copy it to the build directory, which works fine, until I start using UserControls.

My usercontrol(s) contain databindings through a viewmodel to database items. If I understand it correctly, to show usercontrols in the designer, they are built just as if I had run the program. The problem is when they are built in the designer the databindings are also created so some small database queries are executed. But when the usercontrols are built for the designer and tries to execute those queries I get a dllnotfoundexception from the first .dll (the one included). It cannot find the second one.

I thought that adding the second .dll to the GAC would help the first one find it, but it seems I couldn't because according to gacutil "the module was expected to contain an assembly manifest".

Is there any good way to solve this? Am I just being stupid, overlooking something obvious? I tried to be as clear as possible in describing the problem, if something is not clear, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the DllNotFoundException I get when I open a usercontrol in designer mode causes visual studio to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to copy the sqlite dlls to one of the below locations depends on the version of VS.NET you are using...

One way to find the designer assembly probe location is

1. locate the devenv.exe file.
2. Open the devenv.exe.config file in notepad
3. look for entry in it

   ```
    <probing privatePath="PublicAssemblies;PrivateAssemblies"/>
   ```
4. Copy those sqlite dlls to one of those directories.
5. Restart Visual studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That seemed to fix it, thanks. Also thanks to the nuget suggestion, it also looked great so I'll definately remember that for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use NuGet package Manager and install SQLite

http://nuget.org/

http://nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

btw. there is a x64 version of SQLite also

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us any details of the SQLite files in involved, so the following is my best guess:

Most probably you have a .NET dll which is the ADO.NET Data Provider for SQLite, the other is probably a non .NET dll which is the SQLite itself. You just need that in the same place as the ADO.NET Data Provider dll

Comment: The two files involved are System.Data.SQLite.dll. That one can be added as a reference. The other one is SQLite.Interop.dll.

But the thing is, everything works wonderfully when I run the program. What isn't working is usercontrols. Visual studio just crashes when I open a usercontrol (designer mode) that has databindings to database items.